# ZF2: TableGateway ResultSet to JSON

Tags: php, json, zend-framework2

I am trying to return data from my database to JSON in Zend Framework 2. I am using a TableGateway right now and it returns a ResultSet. But the JsonModel cannot show the resultset. **So is there a way to convert it, or is there an other way to access my database?**

The IndexAction in the HomeController

```
public function indexAction()
{
    return new JsonModel(array(
        'posts' => $posts,
        'resources' => $resources,
        'style' => $style,
        'imgStyle' => $imgStyle,
        'success' => true,
    ));
}
```

The function that returns the resultset

```
public function fetchAll()
{
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) {
        $select->order('date DESC');
    });
    return $resultSet;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you have already done this in module.config.php:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'strategies' => array(
        'ViewJsonStrategy',
    ),
),
```

My next suggestion would be to convert the result to array.

```
$resultSet->toArray();
```

OR

```
$return = array();

foreach( $resultSet as $r )
    $return[]=$r;
```

Your return new JsonModel, is correct.

Comment: toArray() will not work so I converted it to an array by hand!

Comment: Yes, in fact toArray will fail if you fetch it to a class, not sure why, it would be useful to have the function toArray() always working :), I am sure the zf2 developers may have a good reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\Reflection`-hydrator, either in the `fetchAll` method in or the `Controller`:

```php
public function __construct(\Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\Reflection $hydrator)
{
    $this->hydrator = $hydrator;
}

public function fetchAll() : array 
{
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) {
        $select->order('date DESC');
    });
    $return = [];
    foreach($resultSet as $result) {
        $return[] = $this->hydrator->extract($result);
    }
    return $return;
}
```